# HDD not mounting

Tags: debian, filesystems, mount

I had a small PC which was booting via USB, OS was on the USB, plus a data SATA SSD and an external USB HDD.  Debian 11 is the OS.

I recently installed an M.2 drive and cloned, using Clonezilla, the USB boot drive to it.  I then removed the USB boot drive.

Now when I boot, via M.2, the SSD fails to mount.  I have discovered if I have a cron with the command "mount -a" scheduled to run at boot the SSD is now mounted and all is good.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The fact that `mount -a` helps suggests a timing issue. Is the data SSD being mounted to a sub-directory of the external USB HDD? Then it might be that the switch to a M.2 boot drive made the boot happen so much faster that the USB HDD cannot spin up in time, and the attempt to mount the data SSD becomes unhappy because the mount point does not exist until the USB HDD is mounted.

Comment: No, the SSD data is not being mounted to a sub=directory of the external USB HDD.  Any ideas how to test your timing issue as that was my first thought as it worked for years via the USB boot drive without issues.  Just means odd that transferring to boot drive to another drive causes issues, and speed was my first thought.